# TKinter : Image preview - Buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

What's the easiest way to make a GUI in python ([TKinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)) that recieves an array of 5 images (urls), shows them side by side with 3 buttos in front.

As you click button1 it append a text1 do a file1 if you do the same on button2 a text2 to a file2.

I want to do this for lots (7000) groups of 5 pics

Something like this:

```
IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE           BUT1 BUT2 BUT3

IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE           BUT1 BUT2 BUT3

IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE           BUT1 BUT2 BUT3


previous page<  ----  >next page
```

Some pointers? Would this be easier another way?

Maybe I wasnt clear enough.

Input: 7000 groups of 5 pics each.
    each group can be of one of the 3 tags

Examples would be greatly apreciated

Comment: are you aware of the contradictions in your question? You say you want the buttons "in front" yet  your example shows them at the end of a row. You say the GUI accepts an array of five images, yet your example shows 15 images.

Comment: Cultural differences (by in front I mean in the end of the row). And my example shows 15 images because it shows 3 groups of images..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're after when you ask for the "easiest way". There are at least a couple solutions, both of which are very straight-forward. You can either choose to organize your "page" as a grid, putting each image and button in a column, or you could create an object that represents one row and then create an instance of that row for each group of five. Both solutions are very easy.

Comment: Thanx for the ideas. You don't know of any examples with (at least) 2 images and 2 buttons?? (I know I know..... read the manual :) )